# Was the ability to run a .NET Core app from source code removed?

Tags: .net-core

In previous versions of what is now .NET Core, using the dnx toolchain, it was possible to run an application straight from source code, without compiling to a DLL on disk. This capability was also present on Azure, allowing you to edit code on the server and have those changes reflected in the live site.

The new `dotnet` CLI `run` command seems to automatically create the familiar `bin` and `obj` folders with compiled DLLs in them, and the publish process from Visual Studio to Azure now no longer includes the C# source, just the DLL.

Is it no longer possible with the new CLI and other tools to run .NET Core code without creating a DLL on disk?

Comment: You can use C# interactive: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/C%23-Interactive-Walkthrough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short David Fowler [response](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1473):

> Dynamic compilation is gone in RC2. It only exists for views now. There are no plans to bring it back.

Why?

> Architectural challenges and changes require to implement it on both .NET Framework and .NET Core. We did it with dnx and there were some problems (like some things being completely broken with in memory assemblies) that we chose to just avoid.